# computation of test data in tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was going through the tutorial of tensorflow-
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))    #weights
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))         #bias   
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Towards the very end, we pass in test data to the placeholders. y_ is matrix containing true values. and y is the matrix with predicted values. My question is when is y computed for the test data. The W matrix has been trained by backpropagation. But this trained matrix must be multiplied with new input x (test data) to give the prediction y. Where does this happen?

Normally i have seen sequential execution of code, and in the last few lines, y isn't called explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accuracy` depends on `correct_prediction` which depends on `y`.

So when you call `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})`, `y` is computed before `accuracy` is computed. All this happen inside the TensorFlow graph.

---

The TensorFlow graph is the **same** for train and test. The only difference is the data you feed to the placeholders `x` and `y_`.

Comment: I had a feeling that it's working exactly as you mentioned in your answer. Can you suggest me some source from where i can read more about TensorFlow graph?

Comment: You can read [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html) on constructing a TF graph, and [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/graph_viz/index.html) on visualizing it.

Answer (score 2):

`y` is computed here:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) # Line 7
```

specifically what you are looking for is with in that line:

```
tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

the output of which is put through the softmax function to identify the class.

This is computed in each of the 1000 passes through the graph, each time the variables `W`, and `b` are updated by GradientDescent and `y` is computed and compared against `y_` to determine the loss.